# Handle interafce orientation change happened beyond my viewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uikit, orientation

I have `UIViewController` that acts like container for several other viewcontrollers. Each of that sub-viewControllers is added as a child, and only one can be visible at the moment. The problem is: when I rotate the device, container viewController handles rotation properly, as well as currently displayed child view controller. Off screen view controllers are resized properly as well, but don't receive any messages and I don't know when I should update it's contents. Is there any method of handling this, or should I instead do this all manually, e.g. storing last orientation for each viewcontroller, checking in `viewWillAppear:` if orientation has changed and do update manually if nescessary?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation` in `viewWillAppear:` and adjust your views appropriately.

Also you can send orientation change message to child viewControllers, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3338530/187663).